# Write asynccomponent in react router config for lazy loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm new to react. Trying to lazy load the components. Am using server side rendering along with react router config. I need to lazy load the components.

asyncComponent.js

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

export default class  extends PureComponent {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  Component: null
}
}

componentWillMount() {
if(!this.state.Component) {
  this.props.moduleProvider().then( ({Component}) => this.setState({ Component }));
}
}

render() {
const { Component } = this.state;

//The magic happens here!
return (
  <div>
    {Component ? <Component /> : ''}
  </div>
);
 }
 };
```

Route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './app';
import asyncComponent from './asyncComponent';

const Home = asyncComponent.moduleProvider(import('./components/Home'));

const routes = [{
    component: App,
    routes: [
        {
          path : '/',
          exact: true,
          component: Home
        }
    ]
}];

export default routes;
```

I have refered the example from [https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/react-webpack-lazy-loading.git][1]

This is throwing exception. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Can you post the error you are facing?

Comment: Only string can be assinged to component.

Comment: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Comment: Change the declaration of `Home` to `const Home = <AsyncComponent moduleProvider={import('./components/Home')} />;`

Comment: WARNING in ./client/routes.js
24:11-28:5 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Comment: error: [unhandledRejection] TypeError: require.ensure is not a function